# Oneliner style addon for chrome

Tags: chrome

I'm a massive fan of [Oneliner - its an addon for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/prospector-oneLiner/) that compacts all the controls into one line. I use it with a few tweaks (with the current Australis theme - there's no firefox button so I've moved over the download and bookmark buttons to the left.

I basically need a theme, addon or something else that will let me do the same thing

[image]

is what firefox looks like for me. The favicon only tabs are optional, but I basically want a way to access bookmarks, my tabs, and the omnibar in a single compact line.

In short:

- needs to run in Chrome - I primarily run canary so it doesn't *necessarily* need be in the app store, but I'd prefer it should I choose to make the switch.
- compacts omnibar|tabs|bookmarks|OS window controls preferably in that order. If the window controls are on the left ala OS X or Ubuntu's unity, then I'd rather it follow the OS preference.

Comment: I don't believe Chrome extensions are capable of rearranging the browser chrome like that.